# Tabbedpage is not being displayed but im getting 0 errors

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, tabbedpage

I am trying to create a bottom navigation bar in xamarin android by using tabbedpage however it dosen't actually exist once i debug the app.

xaml- front-end:

```
 <TabbedPage.Children >
        <NavigationPage Title="Upload">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Upload/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Events" >
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Events/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Projects" >
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Projects/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Registration">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Registration/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

c# - back-end:

```
 public partial class TabbedPage : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
    {

        public TabbedPage()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
          On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's generally a bad idea to give a child class the same name as it's parent

Comment: @Jason i dont even know what that means

Comment: you have a class `TabbedPage` that inherits from `Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage`.  This is confusing at best, and more than likely is causing the compiler to pick the wrong class.

Comment: i kinda agree with Jason here!!

Comment: First,as Json said,you should not name your class  this way，second, pages or the Tabs are not displayed ？

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Tabs

Answer (score 0):

i test on my side,it occurs when the Tabs are more than 3，this is the default behavior for Android. Your tabs are still there - tap on the spots where they should be and you'll see the tab change. If you add icons (set the IconImageSource property), the icons will show up even when the text is blank. here give you a workaround.

you could use [Naxam.BottomTabbedPage](https://github.com/NAXAM/bottomtabbedpage-xamarin-forms) as a workaround first

download **Naxam.BottomTabbedPage** nuget.

then let your page extends the `BottomTabbedPage`

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyTabbedPage: BottomTabbedPage
{
    public TabbedPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }
}
```

in MyTabbedPage.xaml add `xmlns:naxam="clrnamespace:Naxam.Controls.Forms;assembly=Naxam.Controls.Forms"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<naxam:BottomTabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TabbedPageDemo.Views"
         xmlns:naxam="clr-namespace:Naxam.Controls.Forms;assembly=Naxam.Controls.Forms"
         x:Class="TabbedPageDemo.Views.MyTabbedPage">
    <NavigationPage Title="Upload">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Upload/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Events" >
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Events/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Projects" >
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Projects/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Registration">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Registration/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</naxam:BottomTabbedPage>
```

and another workaround ,you just need to write a simple effect([NoShiftEffect](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-fully-customize-bottom-tabs-on-android-turn-off-shifting/)) to apply to our Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage.

Comment: I Literally just fixed the problem but thanks for the help.